# How can I convert a common-used code block to a directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code block that I'm using for pagination (next/previous) buttons that I'd like to have at the top of my page and the bottom, but it seems wrong to write it out twice.

I've made directives before, but I'm not too sure how to add in code so that each time I write:

`<pages />`, for example, it'd give me my pagination code block.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cjFz/

As you can see, I have the same code block at the top and the bottom. I'm not sure if maybe `ng-template` is the way to go? Or if I can even get something as tidy as `<pages />`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be as easy not creating a scope and setting the template equal to the block of html you use there. So something like: (I just converted your html to a js string)

```
app.directive('pages', function(){    
    var html = "    <div class=\"pages\">";
        html += "        <button ng-disabled=\"currentPage == 0\" ng-click=\"currentPage=currentPage-1\">";
        html += "            Previous";
        html += "        <\/button>";
        html += "        {{currentPage+1}}\/{{numberOfPages()}}";
        html += "        <button ng-disabled=\"currentPage >= data.length\/pageSize - 1\" ng-click=\"currentPage=currentPage+1\">";
        html += "            Next";
        html += "        <\/button>";
        html += "    <\/div>";
    return {
        template: html,
        scope:false,
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true        
    };
});
```

You could also reference the template directly from your html with an ng-template if you like.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTqYz/)

Comment: Thanks for that, that works great. I wonder if this is common / good practice?

Comment: @Prodikl yep this is the standard way to do it. Although you would probably want to put your template into it's own file instead of a big javascript string. Also you could optionally pass parameters into the directive instead of relying on the scope of the outer controller.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. How could I pass parameters into an element directive like this?

Comment: That would depend on where those variables come from (controller, service,http)?